# Using the "&" (ampersand) operator where the top-most parent is an element tag selector

Tags: css, less

I have this LESS:

###### LESS

```
custom-component {
  .random-class {
    .decorator-class& wrapper {
      ...
    }
  }
```

that yields

###### CSS

```css
.decorator-classcustom-component .random-class wrapper {
  ...
}
```

which outputs gibberish because there is no such class `.decorator-classcustom-component`. This happens because the uppermost parent selector is an HTML element tag and not a class or other selector type.

Is there a way to get the characters before the ampersand (`.decorator-class`) to concatenate on the right side of the uppermost parent selector? Like this:

```css
custom-component.decorator-class .random-class wrapper
```

?

Note that attempting,

```
custom-component {
  .random-class {
    &.decorator-class wrapper {
//  ^ ampersand at the beginning of selector
      ...
    }
  }
```

would yield,

```css
custom-component .random-class.decorator-class wrapper
```

Comment: `&.decorator-class wrapper` ?

Comment: @doğukan that's a good point. I updated the question to bring out the issue. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

I find it really useful to translate CSS selectors to English for debugging in situations like this. Your desired selector `custom-component.decorator-class .random-class wrapper` translates to:

> Select `wrapper` elements inside an element with a class `random-class`, inside a `custom-component` element with the class `.decorator-class`.

If that's what you mean, then you need something like this:

```
custom-component {
  &.decorator-class {
    .random-class wrapper {
      ...
    }
  }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this produce:
`custom-component.random-class .decorator-class wrapper`? That's not my intent.

Comment: Ah - sorry, I mis-read your examples. I updated my code.

Comment: That would work Ben, but I'm interested in the flow above because it lets me implement class switches. I'll add some more information to the Q to explain the technique.

Comment: Ah - I see what you mean now. As far as I know, you can't use `&` to achieve this (I know more about SASS than LESS, but I believe they have the same behaviour here). Think of '&' as a placeholder for 'the compiled selector up to this point, as a string' - you can add things before and after the string, but you can't access the middle of it.